# How can I make SQL Server notify if there is a change in table records

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using C# with ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008.

When any of the rows in a particular table changes, SQL Server should proactively notify the code, that there is change. I will be hitting a stored procedure to fetch the records from table only if the records in the table are changed.

I don't want to use polling.

I have one option : `SqlDependency` class with Service broker.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Personally I always use external messaging services for this type of thing (allows it to extend to anything, not just sql-server); I'm partial to redis pub/sub in particular.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Best way to use SqlDependency?

Comment: We used to have Sql Server Notification services.

Comment: What about a CLR function hooked up to an insert/update/delete trigger that connects to a service in your code (assuming it has a server or other definable component) and informs it that there's been an update?

Comment: I'm calling [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on this question. Having your database broadcast external change notifications is 99% of the time just a patch for bad application security and/or architecture. What's the **real** problem you're trying to solve?